# Определить строку с переносом на новую строку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Необходимо определить полностью параграф контекст которого

Lorem
ipsum
dolor

Если это возможно, с помощью селектора $( p:contains() )

```
<p>
  Lorem<br/> 
  ipsum<br/> 
  dolor
</p>
<p>
  sit<br/> 
  amet,<br/> 
  consectetur
</p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/module/r7jcd8nt/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:contains()` - слабая штука, потому что ищет только по строгому совпадению строки. С ним можно только отдельно проверить каждое слово. При этом, порядок слов не гарантируется.

```js
$("p:contains(Lorem):contains(ipsum):contains(dolor)").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  ipsum<br/>
  Lorem<br/>
  dolor
</p>
<p>
  aaa<br/> 
  bbb<br/> 
  ccc
</p>
```

`.filter()` здесь будет сильно надежнее:

```js
let $p = $("p").filter(function() {
  return /lorem\s+ipsum\s+dolor/i.test( $(this).text() );
});

$p.css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  ipsum<br/>
  Lorem<br/>
  dolor
</p>
<p>
  Lorem<br/>
  ipsum<br/>
  dolor
</p>
<p>
  aaa<br/>
  bbb<br/>
  ccc
</p>
```

`/lorem\s+ipsum\s+dolor/i` — регулярное выражение. Флажок `i` — insensitive, будут учитываться совпадения и заглавными, и маленькими буквами. `\s` — space, любой пробельный символ, `+` один или много раз.

Comment: Пояснил вопрос, пересмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: @Nikolay10987 обновил.

Comment: Похоже без RegEx не обойтись... Благодарен )